# Jenkins: "Restart from stage" not available in my pipeline UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking into the ability of restarting a jenkins pipeline from a failed stage in the middle of it (for example).

I inherited this CI server and am tasked with updating this, so I found this feature to "restart from stage": https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/#restart-from-a-stage

However, I don't see this button exposed on my jenkins UI. I'm guessing it's because my version of jenkins is old.

Here's some info on my server:
Jenkins ver. 2.107
Plugin Info:
Pipeline - 2.5

I can share other plugin info if it helps.

Questions:
1) What do I need to do to get the restart from stage feature?
2) How can I find out next time what version I need to get certain new features (if this is the root cause)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition). Restart stages was added in declarative 1.3. The link should show required dependencies. Ensure they are all present.

Also, note that currently, the UI for restarting a stage in a Declarative Pipeline is only available in the Classic Jenkins UI. Blue Ocean will be adding support for stage restarting in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "Restart from stage" your pipeline UI so you just need do these following steps : -

1 : -  install **workflow-aggregator** plugin and its dependency

[https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator/]

2 : - Restart the jenkins

3 : - Replay the job then onece job is completed then you able to see the restart form stage option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are here in 2021 your pipeline mostly likely is in "Use Groovy Sandbox" mode. Removing the sandbox and approving the pipeline as administrator worked for me to get the replay-button.